# Issue with Syntax in GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have created my GUI I can show you where the execution syntax is suppose to go, I just want to test it to see if it works properly, can you please suggest How I may be able to execute a file or a script, the real purpose of the GUI is to execute a "Shell Script" If you can help with that, that would be great but if you cant then its fine, please just suggest how I may be able to execute a simple file or script. Here is the code, its done but I just need to know the syntax for executing a script or file.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // here the click happend so you can check your Textfield

            String userEntered = txtEnter.getText();

            if(userEntered.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"))
            {
                //run your script
            }
        }
    });
}}
```

Syntax is suppose to go where it says "run script".

Comment: is this what you are looking for? http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-execute-shell-command-from-java/

Answer (score 1):

[ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) is typically used to launch scripts from Java

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("myscript.sh");
builder.start();
```

Comment: So If I add that there it will launch the shell script?

Comment: I got this error when I tried that: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "myscript": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: You're meant to substitute the name of your script for `myscript`

Comment: Can the script be anywhere? For example If I have a script on my desktop and I substitute the name will it work?

Comment: If it's not in your application folder then you have to supply the full path to the script

Comment: Okay thank you, and Just final question, this will work with Shell Script right?

Comment: Yes, did you try it...?

Comment: Yeah I try it, I put the file in the application folder but I get the same error

Comment: @TrollJunior : try to put your `myscript` alongside `.class` file. +1 to the answer, though that will come in some time, my limit is done for today :-)

Comment: I tried that, it wont work, I tried it with an image and a javascript nothing works